# Reflection in inhertited classes

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I use this method to remove `Html` code from my `String`s in classes:

```
public void filterStrings() {

    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    if (fields == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (Field f : fields) {

        if (f.getType() == java.lang.String.class) {

            try {

                String value = (String) f.get(this);

                f.set(this, methodToRemoveHtml(value));

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Works fine. Since I caught myself putting this method in many classes I use, I thought I'd let all those classes inherit from a BaseClass and implement the method only there. 
**But when I do this, I get a:** `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to field not allowed` on every try.

1. Why is this happening and
2. How can I fix this?

Comment: [setAccessible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the fields are private, so they can only be accessed from code inside the class that contains them, and not a superclass.

You have to make them accessible by calling `setAccessible(true);` on them or making them public or protected.

```
    for (Field f : fields) {

        if (f.getType() == java.lang.String.class) {

            try {
                f.setAccessible(true); // make field accessible.
                String value = (String) f.get(this);
                // ...
```

Comment: Yep, that works, thank you very much. I'll accept in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to call:
f.setAccessible(true);